Where to find info about the spy movie "The Night Listener"?
It had something to do with an agent "Z" or with that letter in his "name."  It was set in Russia and, of course, had to do with the KGB.  At the end someone wrote a book and dedicated it (secretly) to someone else who had been of great help (most-likely to the agent with the "Z" name).
It wasn't related to the novel or the other movie (starring Robin Williams) by the same name, though it might have come out around the same time as that other movie (around 2006 with a few years' difference, perhaps).

There is a german movie, "the life of others" http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0405094/ , which basically  has your plot but set in the former GDR, with an agent oft the Stasi, who gets a book dedicated to him at the end...

came here to say "the life of others" - watched (and enjoyed) it a few days ago

Hey, yes!!!  Thanks! That was it.  I'd say, if @ElDuderino would care to put the comment in the form of an answer (since that was the first comment), I'd set it as the right answer.  Though I wonder if I should change the title and some of the content...any ideas...anyone...?  Thanks again! (oh...just noticed: "The liVES of others," according to the IMDB).

Is there any justification behind your thinking that this was the title of this movie, that it's set in Russia, etc.? If so, you should leave the question as it is, because there may be more people looking for it using this (wrong) information. Otherwise you should rewrite the whole question.

@ChanandlerBong, I forget exactly why I used that title.  Perhaps I mistook the title because of the stasi agents who listened-in day AND night, or perhaps there was some listing with that name when I went to watch the movie.  In any case, the answer is correct, and I found it recently at a movie-store.  I think I will leave the title as is for now.

My comment as an answer... with a corrected title.
There is a German movie, The Lives of Others, which basically has your plot, but set in the GDR, with an agent oft the Stasi, who gets a book dedicated to him at the end. 
Enjoy the movie! 
